# Jquery pagination for a table

Tags: jquery

Im using this javascript

http://www.digcode.com/default.aspx?g=posts&t=889

but I need in addition to dynamic pages I need to display static numbering if no data are available the number will be disabled .

Answer (score 0):

you could use a plugin like [datatables](http://datatables.net/) that does pagination (and lot's of other things)